# Type of reaction between (+)-bis salt of (+)-phenylsuccinic acid and HCl

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

Im confused about what type of reaction occurs between the (+)-bis salt of (+)-phenylsuccinic acid and HCl. Would this be considered an acid base reaction or a neautralization reaction?

MY THOUGHTS: I know that an acid-base reaction occurs between (+)-phenysuccinic acid and (-)-proline to make the (bis)+ salt, im confused at to whether such salt is an acid or a base, or neither... If its an acid and an acid, it would be a neutralization reaction mechanism. If it were a base, it would follow an acid-base reaction mechanism. Any thoughts on if either of these make sense based on such info?

Answer (score 0):

The reaction between the bis salt of proline and phenylsuccinic acid will give free phenyl succinic acid and proline hydrochloride as HCl is a much stronger acid than phenylsuccinic acid. All you are really doing is exchanging one acid for another so it is hardly an acid/base reaction.